# How do I install 2XSC Modules in DNN (dotnetnuke)?

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have tried to install several 2XSC modules from this page (http://2sxc.org/en/Apps), but with each of them I get the following message:

**'This package does not appear to be a valid DotNetNuke Extension as it does not have a manifest.'**

Neither the pages on the DNN site nor on Codeplex give any installation instructions.  There also is no *Readme* file with the any of the packages.

Comment: After fumbling around with the app for a while, I see that the applications should supposedly  be installed from within a 2XSC module.  The _getting started_ modal says that there should be a tab on the admin page, but it doesn't seem to exist on my install.  Just have **Home, Data, Views, App, Global** as choices. (DNN 7.4)

Comment: Installation doesn't happen in the App-module, but in the apps-management. That's the 3-gear icon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually here http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/install-2sxc-and-an-app-of-your-choice

Newer apps will automatically point you to this address, older ones don't have that in the zip yet.